# Run a script/program after fast user switching

Tags: macos, authentication

I want to run a little application after a user logs in from fast user switching in OS X. How is this best achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best achieve using [login & logout scripts](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CustomLogin.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW10-BAJCGEGG)

Comment: Note that this is depreciated, and strongly discouraged. From the documentation
--
Important There are numerous reasons to avoid using login and logout scripts:
1) Login and logout scripts are a deprecated technology. In most cases, you should use launchd jobs instead.
2) Login and logout scripts are run as root, which presents a security risk.
3) Only one of each script can be installed at a time. They are intended for system administrators; application developers should not use them in released software.

Comment: Damn 5 minute comment editing limit...
See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8519342/992364) for more modern documentation.